# SQL VS C# aggregation operations performance

Tags: c#, sql, performance

I am writing a Store procedure that has SUM, AVG operation over millions of data with grouping by 3 to 5 column.
I am wondering if i Do this in C# that means If i only read the data from database to C# objects and do the calculation (sum, avg ect.) in the object(or datatable). Will this improve the performance?

I like to create faster application.

Thanks in Advance.
Shuvra

Answer (score 11):

Databases are built to be efficient in sorting, selecting and grouping data. Let it do the work that it is built for. If you do it in C# code you first have to ask the database to deliver all the data and then you have to transfer it to the client. It will be a lot slower than just letting the DB do the calculation.

Comment: Thanks. but in this case my business logic will be in SP rather than business layer.

Answer (score 5):

It would be much better, performance wise, to do the sum, avg operation in your Store Procedure. Because if you want to perform these operation using C#, you have to fetch million of records and on million of records you will have sum, avg operation, that would definitely hurt performance to a much greater extent whereas if you do sum, avg operations in SP, you only have to fetch the summarize records and thus utilizes less bandwidth and boosts performance.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. But i am wondering why in the recent projects business layer is a issue. developers are moving the business logic from SP to business layer (C# classes)?

Comment: When having more complex business rules, C# is far more suitable to express them than T-SQL. Still, the SQL queries to fetch data should be carefully crafted to only get the data that the business layer really needs.

Comment: I'm doing this as well in my applications. My reasons are:
- It's much easier to debug and test C# code
- C# code is object-oriented, while SPs aren't
- you can't easily access remote services from stored procedures (i.e. send an e-mail notification to a client)

Comment: Summarizing the records in SP has nothing to do with the Business logic layer dear. Data Access layer too could call the SP to do insertion/ updation etc. Your business logic layer could call the SP through Data Access layer to get the summarized records.

Comment: So far i know, algorithm complexity is based on Comparison and all math function ultimately work with 1's or 2's complement and that in comparison also. therefore, I am confused why C# in slower than SQL? can you please give some web links please? thanks very much. shuvra

Comment: Its quite simple, fetching millions of records consumes lots of memory and time, and then applying sum or average on them will too consumes lots of time, so overall performance will be damn poor. SQL avg, min etc functions are really optimized and they are designed to be performant.

Comment: Thanks Abdul. I like to know how SQL is optimizing that and can we implement that in C#?

Comment: No you cant obviously because SQL DBMS is managing the database not C#, SQL DBMS knows how to hit the indexes for better perf. not C# etc etc.

Comment: SQl server also fatch the record and need memory like C# object.